# How to disable first form with jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

#### HTML:

```
<div id="container">
  <form id="form" name="form1">
     <input type="text" name="txtbox" value="Enter something" />
     <input name="salam" type="Submit" id="submitbtn" name="Submit" />
  </form>
</div>

 <div id="container1">
  <form id="form1" name="form1">
    <input type="text1" name="txtbox1" value="Enter something" />
    <input name="salam1" type="Submit" id="submitbtn1" name="Submit" />
  </form>
</div>
```

#### jQuery:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $('#form').submit(function(){
      $('input[id=submitbtn1]', this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
   });
 });
```

Comment: `submitbtn1` is in `id="form1"`, but your code supposed that in `'#form'`. Btw your question is not entirely clear to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#form").submit(function (event){
       event.preventDefault();         
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In pure javascript it is also easy:

```
document.getElementById('submitbtn1').disabled = true;
```

OR

```
document.getElementById('submitbtn1').readOnly = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out [first selector](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/)

```
$("form:first input").attr("disabled", true);
```

will select all `input` elements from first `form` element and will disable them.

Comment: That's not the best selector.. $("#container").find("input") is the preferred way.

Comment: @elad.chen What I understood from question is OP wants to disable all `input` elements which are inside a particular `form`. Dont see anywhere OP have mentioned `input` within particular `div`.

Comment: than use: $("#form").find("input")

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#form').submit(function(){
    $('#submitbtn1').attr('disabled', true);
  });
});
```

If you just want to disable button with id = submitbtn1 when submitting form with id=form

Answer (score 0):

this disables it without waiting for the submit

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 
    $('#submitbtn1').attr('disabled', true);
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
 <form id="form" name="form1">
   <input type="text" name="txtbox" value="Enter something" />
   <input name="salam" type="Submit" id="submitbtn" name="Submit" />
 </form>
</div>
<div id="container1">
 <form id="form1" name="form1">
  <input type="text1" name="txtbox1" value="Enter something" />
  <input name="salam1" type="Submit" id="submitbtn1" name="Submit" />
 </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Also this

```
$('input[id=submitbtn1]', this).attr('disabled', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#submitbtn1').attr('disabled', true);

});
```